# Batch script to search and delete a specific filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

I'll explain exactly my situation. I need a batch file that searches C:/ for 'Minecraft.exe' and deletes it if it exists.

I don't know enough batch to be able to do this on my own and I've looked everywhere and all I can find is partial solutions.

Comment: Is this something just for you, or something you plan to share with others? minecraft has a default installation directory that you can just point to rather than searching. I feel like I would not want this batch file to run on my computer, because it would also delete my new copy of minecraft that I wanted to replace the old one with! Or is this just an "uninstaller" for minecraft?

Comment: Its actually going to be deployed over PDQDeploy across a network to delete Minecraft from a bunch of computers that are not supposed to have it. I need every copy gone.

Comment: Ah, well... I assume this is an educational setting. People can still rename minecraft.exe or launch it from a USB drive, though. Not that I know of a better way to block this, but there are a lot of weaknesses in this, I think. Maybe ban the ip for the login server.. I am not sure that would block it entirely though. I think if people knew you were trying to block this program from executing, they'd have better solutions though.

Answer (score 4):

Well - good idea to do this first:

```
DIR /s c:\minecraft.exe
```

But that's just looking for it.

Be VERY, VERY careful with this command - make an error and you could have real trouble.

```
del /p /s c:\minecraft.exe
```

will delete all minecraft.exe (but prompt first)

Omit the `/p` and it'll delete without prompting

Add `/f` and it'll ALSO delete any READ-ONLY versions it finds.

Just be careful, 'k?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it doesn't delete anything before you remove the `echo`):

```
@echo off &setlocal 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /s /b c:\minecraft.exe') do echo del "%%~i"
endlocal
```

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that Minecraft.exe could also be in ANY subdir of C:/ as well. So I actually need to search the entirety of the C:/ drive including subdirs.

Comment: Yes, this does the `dir /s` command, it searches in all folders of C:\.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So it batch you dont need to use any wildcards between dirs? IE C:/%/Minecraft.exe

Comment: No wildcards required if the full name is known (`minecraft.exe`).

Comment: It finds all files of the same names recursively

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late but:

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('Dir c:\Minecraft.exe /s /b') do set FOUND="%%~fI"
del %FOUND%
```

The first line searches the whole C: drive. The second line deletes the file.